# ios/json. URL string to UIImage

Tags: iphone, ios, json, url, uiimage

Wow, I almost gave up....

this is my log for parsed JSon,

```
NSLog(@"http://example.com%@",url1);

2012-04-20 04:14:37.686 Dolls[11070:707] http://example.com/uploads/ed_1.png
```

and

```
NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com%@",url1];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
image = [UIImage  imageWithData:imgData];
```

finally....(I'm using AQGrid...so)

```
[cell.imageView setImage:image];
```

*Cell image is still blank. what did I wrong?*

=======

Figure out cell.imageview loaded before 'image' was still downloading.

In this case, how can I reload [setImage:] method, after image downloaded (or downloading)

Comment: Have you verified that `url` is not nil before using it to load the NSData? Have you verified that `imgData` is not nil before passing it to UIImage? Have you checked whether `image` is nil before giving it to the cell? Doing this simple bit of debugging will help narrow down the problem quite a bit.

Comment: Thank you. I debugged and I found out image is fine, saving right into my library. But I just can't figure it out why it doesn't display with [setImage:].....

Answer (score 0):

Hello if you save your image in local directory then you can use below code to load image from there :

```
- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
}

-(void)loadimage{
    NSString *workSpacePath=[[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"your image-name"];
UIImage *imgLocal = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:workSpacePath]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[SDWebImage lib](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) will completely solve your issue.

Just write:

```
NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://xxx.com%@",url1];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:url];
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
[[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imgData]];
```

Comment: For God's sake, don't do this. This will block the main thread, and it's even worse when it's inside an `UIScrollView`. Please check AFNetworking, SDImageView, or anything else, but don't do this!

Comment: @Marcelo I agree with you - this answer is not helpful at all since it does exactly the same Ghostino does in the question. But it doesn't block the main thread! It has to be called on the main thread otherwise it won't get updated (immediately). Blocking the main thread is what Ghostino does in the question making a synchronous URL request. THAT is indeed very bad UX ...

Comment: This snippet doesn't block the main thread. But OMHO, this answer accepts the fact that the data loading is occurring on the main thread, as suggested on the question: `NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];`.

Comment: @MarceloFabri That's exactly why this answer is IMO useless. But you could download the image data asynchronously and set it like this in the completion block (on the main thread of course).